# HornetQ cluster node consumers

Tags: cluster-computing, mule, hornetq

I have a HornetQ standalone cluster with 2 nodes and Mule ESB is configured to connect HornetQ Cluster discovery group.

I wrote a Mule Callback Listener which is consuming messages from HornetQ Cluster. But 2nd node in cluster is behaving like a backup or failover server. When i send multiple messages its always delivered to node1 only. When i stop node1 then node2 is picking the messages. JConsole always shows number of consumers as 0 for node2. Whereas node1 has 6 consumer as defined in Mule JMS connector->numberOfConsumers property as shown in below configuration.

```
<jms:connector name="hornetq-connector" username="guest" 
    maxRedelivery="5" password="guest" specification="1.1"
    connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" numberOfConsumers="6" >
    <spring:property name="retryPolicyTemplate" ref="ThreadingPolicyTemplate"  />
</jms:connector>
```

I have only one consumer that is defined in mule flow as shown below.

```
<flow name="Flow2" doc:name="Flow2">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="InboundQueue"
     connector-ref="hornetq-connector">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="10000" />
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>

    <component class="com.test.Consumer" />
</flow>
```

Mule Callback java class is added as component as shown in above code (). Please find the code below.

public class Consumer implements org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable{

```
private static DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(df1.format(new Date().getTime())+"Consumer:Message Received,"+ Thread.currentThread()+ "," + eventContext.getMessageAsString());
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println(df1.format(new Date().getTime())+"Consumer: Message process complete, "+ Thread.currentThread()+ ","  + eventContext.getMessageAsString());

    return "Success";
}
```

}

How to distribute this one consumer across all the HornetQ clustered nodes?

Comment: What is this "Mule Callback Listener" you're talking about? A specific extension to the JMS transport? Can you show its code?

Comment: I was able to fix this problem using Mule's composite-source tag by specifying all messages sources. Let me know if you need further information.